# How to install Starry Night on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I wish to install STARRY NIGHT on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Which is the safest way to install this useful application?

Comment: You'll want to use [wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5530)

Comment: Which one: Wine Windows Program Loader or Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)? Will Ubuntu Software Centre show it if I install one of these?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [Starry Night](http://astronomy.starrynight.com/) does not support Linux natively. You could:

1. Try an alternative, such as [Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/), which is available through the Ubuntu Software Center. It's free and open-source!
2. Or try running Starry Night using `wine`. Some features may not work as expected, if you can even get it working at all. For some tips and test results, see the [WineHQ Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5530). For more information on running `wine`, see the [Communiti Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) or search AskUbuntu.

Comment: I had used Stellarium once. It is a good one. But I want the best one itself. It has many more good features

Comment: Just installed Stallarium snap on 20.04.3 via command line... it's awesome!!!